# How to make css rules applied when changing to landscape mode?

Tags: sass, media-queries

I need my page to adapt from portrait to landscape for Iphone X without having to reload the page.

Here are the media Queries I use:

```
// Screen size variables
$screen-sm-min: 576px;  // Small tablets and large smartphones (landscape view)

$screen-lg-min: 992px;  // Tablets and small desktops
//$screen-lg-min: 1024px;
$screen-xl-min: 1200px; // Large tablets and desktops


// Mixins
@mixin xs { @media (max-width: #{$screen-sm-min}),
        (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width : 667px),
        (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px),
        (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width : 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3)

{@content;} } // Tiny devices


@mixin md { @media (max-width: #{$screen-lg-min}), (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px),
            (min-device-height : 1024px) and (max-device-width : 1366px)

    {@content;} } // Medium devices
```

And here is a link to the page:

http://dev2.lemeilleurducbd.com/location_etu/home.html

I have looked on Google but I could not find an answer to this issue.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### CSS solution

You can use [orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation) in media queries.

**landscape** rules apply when the browser window width is greater than height:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
    ...
}
```

**portrait** rules apply when browser window height is greater than width:

```
@media (orientation: portrait) {
    ...
}
```

#### JS solution ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation#Preventing_orientation_change))

Note: Unfortunately this feature is not supported in safari.

You can listen to the `orientationChange` event for when the orientation changes, and read `screen.orientation` when you need to know the current orientation.

```
screen.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () { 
    console.log("screen orientation: " + screen.orientation); 
});
```

---

Another option would be to listen to window resizes and compare the ratio of width and height.

`if (width/height > 1) { //landscape } else { portrait }`.

I recommend throttling the window resize listener.

Comment: Thanks for for response, but adding those 2 Media Queries does not change anything, I need the css to adapt when changing to landscape mode, i.e I must find a way (with Javascript maybe ?) to detect that the landscape mode is activated and then refresh css,

Comment: @learner I added a couple JavaScript possibilities. I think the first one doesn't have safari support yet

Answer (score 0):

I put a piece of javascript on the body tag, that was adapting the body width according to the windowWith, this is what was preventing to go on landscape mode without reloading the page..